# A special case of excess intersection formula?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is Example 3.3.2 in Fulton's "Intersection Theory":

> **Example 3.3.2.** Let $\pi:E\to X$ be a vector bundle of rank $r$ over an algebraic scheme $X$ with zero section $s:X\to E$. As $\pi^*$ induce isomorphism $A_{k-r}X\to A_kE$. Hence we define $s^*:=(\pi^*)^{-1}$. Now let $F=E\oplus 1$ and $Q=P(F)=\underline{\mathrm{Proj}}_X\mathrm{Sym}(\mathscr{F}^{\vee})$ where $\mathscr{F}$ be the sheaf of sections of $F$. Let $q:Q\to X$ and $j:E\to Q$.
>
> Now we have a universal sequence $$0\to\mathscr{O}_{Q}(-1)\to q^*F\to \xi\to0$$ over $Q$. Fulton showed that in Proposition 3.3 that if $\beta\in A_kE$ with lift $\beta'\in A_k(Q)$, then we have $s^*\beta=q_*(c_r(\xi)\cap\beta')$.
>
> Now in this Example they claim that $s^*s_*\alpha=c_r(E)\cap\alpha$ for all $\alpha\in A_*X$.

Now let $\beta=s_*\alpha$ and $\beta':=\hat{s}_*\alpha$ where $\hat{s}=j\circ s$ be the induced section. Then we have
\begin{align*}
&q_* (c_r(\xi)\cap\bar{s}_* (\alpha))\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^r q_* (c_1(\mathscr{O}_{E\oplus 1}(1))^ic_{r-i}(q^*E)\cap\bar{s}_* (\alpha))\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^r c_{r-i}(E)q_* (c_1(\mathscr{O}_{E\oplus 1}(1))^i\cap\bar{s}_* (\alpha))\\
&=c_r(E)\cap\alpha+\sum_{i=1}^r c_{r-i}(E)q_* (c_1(\mathscr{O}_{E\oplus 1}(1))^i\cap\bar{s}_* (\alpha))\\
&=???
\end{align*}
So I don't know why the term
$$\sum_{i=1}^r c_{r-i}(E)q_* (c_1(\mathscr{O}_{E\oplus 1}(1))^i\cap\bar{s}_* (\alpha))$$
vanish?

Thank you for your any help!!!

Comment: If you prove $c_1(\mathcal{O}(1))\cap \overline{s}_*(\alpha)=0$ then you are done. But now you have $c_1$ of a line bundle so you can intersect $\overline{s}_*(\alpha)$ with a divisor associted to it. Finally remember the definition of $\overline{s}_*$.

Comment: Thank you very much！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has solved, see Wiktor Vacca's comment:

> If you prove $c_1(\mathcal{O}(1))\cap \overline{s}_*(\alpha)=0$ then you are done. But now you have $c_1$ of a line bundle so you can intersect $\overline{s}_*(\alpha)$ with a divisor associated to it. Finally remember the definition of $\overline{s}_*$.

Comment: Comments can disappear without warning - it's best to include the text of the comment in your answer when you're marking a question as answered this way. I've taken the liberty of adding the text for you this time.